# How can I tell TypeScript that my isFinite is even better than typeof any === 'number'?

Tags: typescript

I have a simple method for number checking:

```
/**
 * Uses Number.isFinite or combination of checks against typeof, itself (NaN) and Infinity
 * @param input
 */
export function isFinite(input: any) :boolean {
    if (isFunction(Number.isFinite)) { // another check, which goes typeof input === 'function'
        return Number.isFinite(input);
    }
    return (typeof input === 'number') && (input !== input) && (input !== Infinity);
}
```

Now I am using it in another method for an optional parameter like this

```
export function setSessionCookie(token: string, expireHours ?: number) :void {
    const STORAGE_KEY = 'userToken';
    if (!isFinite(expireHours)) {
        expireHours = 48;
    }
    const now = new Date();

    // here I get an "Object is possibly 'undefined'. ts(2532)" for 'expireHours'
    now.setTime((now.getTime() + (expireHours * 60 * 60 * 1000)));
    const expire = now.getTime();
    const STORAGE_VALUE = {
        token: token,
        expire: expire
    };
    window.localStorage.removeItem(STORAGE_KEY);
    window.localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(STORAGE_VALUE));
}
```

#### I can use `(expireHours || 1)` in the line in question, but this is a nightmare.

#### Replacing the if condition with `typeof exireHours !== 'number'` would resolve the problem

But then I still might have an `NaN` at this point.

#### Solution?

`expireHours` is a number, not an or in an object at all, so I also might get the error message wrong. But this is not my main point here: the check for being `undefined` is a great job for avoiding `NaN` as result, for which I am using TS.

In terms of **working with the TS compiler, not against it**, how can I improve either my checking method or its usage here in order to tell TS that everything is fine when I start calculating with the parameter. Is adding another variable the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have the parameter marked as optional, so the compiler rightly complains that it could be undefined. You can 'fix' this one of three ways:

1. Asserting the type to the compiler
2. Give the optional parameter a default value
3. Using a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).

Such a type guard would look like this:

```
function isNumber(n: any): n is number {
    return typeof n === 'number';
}
```

Then it just works:

```
function isFinite(n: number): boolean {
    if (typeof Number.isFinite === 'function') {
        return Number.isFinite(n);
    } else {
        return typeof n === 'number' && n === n && n !== -Infinity && n !== Infinity
    }
}


function bar(n?: number) {
    const x: number = isNumber(n) && isFinite(n) ? n : 48;
    const y = x * 60000;
    return y;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAZgrgdgxgLgSwPZQAQIM4DkIFsBGApgE4AUUAXKgIZQCeAlFWpqlHkcagN6ir+pihOBGJo4dAA6EkYNqgC8S1AHJ2BEioDcoAL6hQkWIhToMAMQRQEcQuWYcSTVPiRIANoVo8+AhHNIJaVlUHA1iADpMS2tbRWUVI3hkKBUGHxABLMFhUTQwziiLKxs7KAYdTIFdVEJ3DEIM7IEhETFUIJk5NCUFVXVOFVQAMmH5XvlR+QBCZQBaAEkoMBKJEbG0Wb6lldi6X359ECODcGhk03xqMigAfgdw9N4q-k84VAAPB85FMwKScjpKbRVZldK3eRUAAsAA5KlkYCgMO86L8PqgAFSoABsAAZ8bj4S1cu06JUjkA)

Note that the type guard function is not strictly necessary here since we're talking about a primitive value like number:

```
function bar(n?: number) {
    const x: number = typeof n === 'number' && isFinite(n) ? n : 48;
    const y = x * 60000;
    return y;
}
```

works just as well but it can be tedious to type `typeof x === 'number'` over and over.

If you don't mind just putting the default value in the function signature it also works:

```
function bar(n: number = 48) {
    const x: number = isFinite(n) ? n : 48;
    const y = x * 60000;
    return y;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am now using a default value for the parameter. I was not aware of this option in JS yet and it is not supported by IE and Safari < 10 AFAIK. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters

Comment: @BairDev that is correct, but if I had to limit my Javascript to what IE supports I would literally quit my job. You can set the target version of the output in the tsconfig options, set it to whatever you need to support and it will compile it to the older idioms. Or for non-TS projects use babel :)

Comment: @BairDev dev if you have a new question, ask a new question.